# XSLT: Using copy-of to output xml

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, escaping

I am using the copy-of element in xsl to print some xml to client, but the xslt outputs the unescapes the escaped xml characters to the output e.g.

if the xml being transformed is

<one attr="http://one.com/page?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2">
   <child>text</child>

</one>

and if i use the copy-of to output this node <xsl:copy-of select"."></>

the output converts the "&amp;" in attribute **attr** to just "&" which causes xml parse error on client.

how can i preserve the escaped xml characters when outputting the xml

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,

Keshav

Comment: What are you using to do the transform?

Comment: i am doing transform to render an HTML but i want to preserve some parts of XML in div tags so that i can process them later if required

Comment: Yes, but what's actually doing the transform? Are you using .NET, Java, or some other platform? Also, once you've done the transform, how are you passing it to the client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't reproduce the problem. Provided full stylesheet and your processor.
This

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Return:

```
<one attr="http://one.com/page?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2">
<child>text</child>
</one>
```

And this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Return:

```
<one attr="http://one.com/page?param1=value1&amp;param2=value2"> <child>text</child> </one>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you use `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` the XSLT processor *must* produce well-formed XML document (or fragment).

Not producing such indicates a bug in the used XSLT processor and you need to report it to its developers and ask for a fix or workaround.

Comment: hi
thanks for the reply, yes you are right it should be a problem with the xsl processor in such case. but it turned out that this happened because of some internal processing we were doing.